# Lizard Lip nickname

Tags: meaning, idiom-meaning

I'm translating the titles of the old black-and-white movie *Hard Luck,* directed by Buster Keaton. His titles often contain plays on words and puns. One of the titles shows the poster on the wall:

> $5000 reward for the capture of "Lizard Lip Luke",
> bandit and train robber.

This bandit's nickname is confusing to me. 
Bandit Luke is played by a burly man, who has nothing in common with lizards. 
Does this nickname have some idiomatic meaning? 
Or maybe this nickname emphasizes dry lips or thin lips of the character? 
Or it is just 'lip of the lizard' without any concealed meaning?

Comment: It's *entirely* a matter of opinion which if any specific features of lizard "lips" you associate with the nickname. And I don't see why it should be any different for non-Anglophones - who presumably would have equivalent words for ***lizard*** and ***lip*** in their own language, and can decide for themselves what the combination makes them think of.

Comment: Does the character have a wide mouth with thin to non-existent lips? If so, there's your answer.

Comment: It's done purely for the sound of it - [alliteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliteration).

Comment: I had a friend Daryl who once tried to kiss his iguana Happy Birthday. It bit him on the lip. We called Daryl "Lizard Lips after that.

Comment: @HotLicks Wow, nice remark. Haven't thought about alliteration. As this character has got very ordinary lips (hence no direct relation to a lizard) my main concern was to ask native speakers about possible idiomatic meaning of this phrase. If this word combination has no specific meaning of course I can translate it directly.

Comment: @whtyger - I looked at his pictures online. He was apparently wearing a fairly large mustache in the movie, and his lips are kind of thin, so the appellation isn't totally out in left field.  But very likely the script writers picked the name before he was cast for the part.

Comment: Main point in the translation is to pick something in the target tongue that is some kind of slur. I would not try hard to match the original words, but the original intent: the bandit is bad and looks bad.

Comment: @HotLicks - Joe Roberts appeared in almost all Buster Keaton shorts, so he was cast without competition. And script of these shorts frequently appeared right in the process of filming. So that's not the case. Titles of Keaton's films are full of play on words. That's why I wanted to double check the meaning. If you write your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I voted to close because it is unclear what the question is asking. Please edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Lawrence, I was asking whether this combination of words has some special meaning. My native language isn't English so I obviously cannot know all idioms of this language. I checked https://www.urbandictionary.com prior to asking and its versions weren't satisfactory. That's why I decided to ask native speakers. I've got an answer that this nickname possibly has no any special meaning so I can translate it 'as is'. I can edit my question but I can't think how I can improve it.

Comment: @Lawrence, I added some explanation, but that's the best I can do.

Comment: There's no pun. It's two things - alliteration, and something distasteful but for general audience (not salacious). 'lizard lips' sounds like a slur, as though thin lips are ugly. It sounds very old-fashioned.

Answer (score 1):

It is common in cowboy storytellings to have nicknames for villains in order to build fear of, or hatred toward them. This serves the plot to make the conflict more dramatic and the victory sweeter or more satisfying. Alliteration is often more important that any kind of accuracy. Simple examples, *Slippery Sam* and *Dead-eye Duke* are a few that come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

As Elliot said, alliteration is more important than anything here- for example in Spanish the bad guy could be "Lucas Labio de Lagarto" or "Lucas Labio de Lagartija". Whatever language you are translating to, definitely his nickname is just Luke lip of lizard, as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You're quite right. Bandit Luke has nothing in common with lizards.

Watching Hard Luck just now, it's obvious the only - and even that, irrelevant - reference to lizards is when our hero sets off to find the zoo an armadillo… that's it.

Including lots of the ladies, the Luke character looks to be the least lizard-like lad in the whole movie. His lips don't look dry nor straight or thin and he doesn't seem significantly unsmiling…

That some scriptwriter seems to have thought the alliteration more important than its possible meaning seems silly… but so is everything else about that movie, from the pointless title on…